# WooCommerce shipping charges isssue with PayPal

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

Issue in WooCommerce Shipping Calculation with PayPal

Currently Using WooCommerce for cake store and using PayPal for payment gateway.

I have created $5 discount for store pickup. So ideally a $50 product should be $45. That reflects in the website.

But when user goes to "Payment via PayPal", it still shows $50.

Any suggestions how to override shipping calculations of PayPal on WooCommerce?

I saw many articles on google but can't find the appropriate solution.

I also checked the box on override allow transaction-based postage values to override the profile postage settings listed above (if profile settings are enabled), but with no luck.

Can any one help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try? Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to resolve the issue, but perhaps the most straightforward would be to switch to a PayPal payment plugin that uses an API instead of Payments Standard, for example this official one: https://woocommerce.com/woocommerce-and-paypal/ (there are also various third party ones available)

Then, profile shipping settings in the PayPal account will not affect WooCommerce transactions in any way, since everything about the transaction will be set via the API. This is also a more robust and feature-rich solution in general, and so recommended by both PayPal and most programmers/developers familiar with PayPal integration methods.